# Poor Performance of Android app

Tags: android

I had written a crawler program in C# which **used to crawl on a given url or url postfixed with page number and download all the image files from it**.It worked fine.
Now I am a newbie in android programming and thought to write the same thing for my android device so that I can also use it on my phone.

The algorithm I followed was...

1) Take the base url,start page no(in case the url is postfixed by page number in query string),end page no,and location to store the images on sdcard.

2) If end page no is less than start page no(means if i only want to crawl a single page) pass it to getHtml method. or else make a loop from start to end page and pass each url to getHtml method.

3) In getHtml method I download web page source and broke it in pieces to find link to image files in it.

4) for each image url found, download the image file to the given save location.

**The algo seems easy but when I made the whole program I had some pretty big performance issues. It is so so heavy that while running it in emulator all i could see was gc clearing objects in logcat.Another very common issue is that the UI hangs.But as the program is only for personal use i can do with it because I doesnt know multithreading in android. But atleast the program should be fast. Is there any way I can decrease the number of objects or destroy them myself.**

Is there anything I can do to improve this. I wonder how those GBs worth of games works flawlessly and my 20KB app is so so slow.

The whole code is.

```
package com.dwnldr;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class IMGDwnldrActivity extends Activity {

    EditText res;
    String str;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        EditText saveat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        saveat.setText(SDCardRoot.getAbsolutePath());
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
//Getting URL,Start pageno,End pageno and the save location on sdcard
                    EditText baseurl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    String url = baseurl.getText().toString();
                    EditText startpage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    int start = Integer.parseInt(startpage.getText().toString());
                    EditText endpage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    int end = Integer.parseInt(endpage.getText().toString());
                    EditText saveat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                    String save = saveat.getText().toString();
                    if (start <= end) {
                        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                            str = "\n--------------------";
                            str += "\nPage No" + String.valueOf(i);
                            writemsg(str);
                            getHtml(url + String.valueOf(i), save);
                        }
                    } else
                        getHtml(url, save);
                    writemsg("Done");
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    writemsg("\nException fired::" + ee.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
//method to get the source of a particular url

    public void getHtml(String url, String save) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
            String result = "";
            str = "\nDownloading Page....";
            writemsg(str);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().
                    getContent()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line + "\n";
            }
            str = "\nPage Downloaded...";
            writemsg(str);
            String[] pieces;
            if (result.contains(".jpg") || result.contains(".jpeg")) {
                pieces = result.split("\"");
                Log.d("Events", String.valueOf(pieces.length));
                for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
                    if (pieces[i].contains(".jpg") || pieces[i].contains(".jpeg")) {
                        if (pieces[i].contains("http")) {
                            Log.d("Events", pieces[i]);
                            downloadme(pieces[i], save);
                        } else {
                            URL u = new URL(url);
                            if (pieces[i].startsWith("."));
                            pieces[i] = pieces[i].substring(pieces[i].indexOf("/"), pieces[i].length());
                            writemsg(u.getProtocol() + "://" + u.getHost() + pieces[i]);
                            if (pieces[i].startsWith("/"))
                                downloadme(u.getProtocol() + "://" + u.getHost() + pieces[i], save);
                            else
                                downloadme(u.getProtocol() + "://" + u.getHost() + "/" + pieces[i], save);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            writemsg("\nException fired::" + ee.getMessage());
        }
    }
//download each image url given

    private void downloadme(String url1, String save) {
        try {
            str = "\nDownloading Image " + url1;
            writemsg(str);
            URL url = new URL(url1);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            File f = new File(save);
            if (f.isDirectory() && !f.exists())
                f.mkdirs();
            String fileName = url1.substring(url1.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url1.length());
            File file = new File(save, fileName);
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            str = "\nImage Size " + String.valueOf(totalSize / 1024);
            writemsg(str);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutput.close();
            str = "\nDownloaded Image " + url1;
            writemsg(str);
         catch some possible 
            errors //             ...

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            writemsg("\nException fired::" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            writemsg("\nException fired::" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            writemsg("\nException fired::" + ee.getMessage());
        }
    }
//write certain text to the Result textbox

    private void writemsg(String msg) {
        res = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);
        String str = res.getText().toString();
        str += msg;
        res.setText(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just want to add that the program is running fine. I have tried it on emulator and my phone both. The only problem is performance...

Comment: don't do network requests on the main UI thread.  you need to use threads, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: And avoid string concatenation (`str += ...`), especially in a loop: that creates an object every time. Use a StringBuilder instead.